# Sorting JSON contents by Category

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, sorting

I have a JSON file setup like this:

```
{
    "Products": [
        {   "Name": "Pink Floyd",
            "Album": "The Best Of Pink Floyd: A Foot In The Door",
            "Label": "EMI UK",
            "Tracks":"Hey You, See Emily Play, The Happiest Days Of Our Lives, Another Brick in The Wall (Part 2), Have a cigar, Wish You Where Here, Time, The Great Gig in the Sky, Money, Comfortably Numb, High Hopes, Learning to Fly, The Fletcher Memorial Home, Shine On You Crazy Diamond, Brain Damage, Eclipse" ,
            "Price": "16.40",
            "Genre": "Rock"   ,
            "Source": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/38/AFootInTheDoorPinkFloyd.jpg/220px-AFootInTheDoorPinkFloyd.jpg",
            "Quantity": 10

        },
        {
            "Name": "Depeche Mode",
            "Album": "A Question Of Time",
            "Label": "Mute",
            "Tracks":"A Question Of Time, Black Celebration, Something To Do, Stripped, More Than A Party, A Question Of Time(extended), Black Celebration" ,
            "Price": "4.68" ,
            "Genre": "Rock",
            "Source": "http://dmremix.be/images/AQuestionOfTime.jpg",
            "Quantity": 10
        }, 

..........

        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to sort the categories by 'Genre', i.e. each time I click a 'genre' link, all the products are cleared from the table and only the items having a Genre of 'x' will be displayed.

This is what I tried:

```
<script>

        function Categories(Genre)
        {
            $.getJSON('products.json', function(data) {
                $(".products").empty();
                $(data.Products.Genre).each(function(index, item){
                if(Genre == this.Genre){

                    $('<div/>', {'class':'productname',text:item.Name}).append(
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Album: '+item.Album}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails'}).append($('<img>').attr({src:item.Source,title:item.Name,alt:item.Name,class:'productimage'})),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Genre: '+item.Genre}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Price: '+item.Price}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Quantity: '+item.Quantity}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Tracks: '+item.Tracks}),
                            $('<div/>').append(
                                    $('<button />', {'class':'productbutton'})
                                            .text('Add To Cart.')
                                            .click(function(){
                                                $.fn.SaveToCart(i,item.Name, item.Album, item.Price);
                                            })
                            )
                    ).appendTo("#products");
                }
            });


        });

        }
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="categories">


        <h2>Categories</h2>
        <ul>

            <li><a class=""  onclick="Categories('Rock')"><span>Rock</span></a></li>
            <li><a class=""  onclick="Categories('Electro')"><span>Electro</span></a></li>
            <li><a class=""  onclick="Categories('Hip Hop')"><span>Hip Hop</span></a></li>
            <li><a class=""  onclick="Categories('Ambient')"><span>Ambient</span></a></li>
            <li><a class=""  onclick="Categories('Electronica')"><span>Electronica</span></a></li>
            <li><a class=""  onclick="Categories('Future Garage')"><span>Future Garage</span></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>            <br><br><hr><hr>
<div class="products"></div>
```

When I click on a link, nothing is happening.

Comment: Don't you guess it ? :)

Comment: What sort of error are you getting?

Comment: Try `$(data.Products.Genre).each` to `$(data.Products).each`

Comment: Also, you could filter easily using `Array.filter`: `data.Products.filter(function(i) { return i.Genre == 'Rock' });`

Comment: @Sirko Sorry. When I click the link, nothing is happening.

Comment: @CezaryWojcik No errors, just nothing is happening.

Comment: @JonathandeM. Nope, I had tried that before, to no avail.

Comment: maybe the path of your json, try to put some alert to check where your code stop working

Comment: @JonathandeM. The path is correct. I am able to fetch all the products, but when it comes to sorting by category, nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some errors corrected there :

- Loop on data.Products instead of data.Products.Genre
- Compare to item instead of this
- Append to .products instead of #products that does not exists,
  according to your HTML !

Don't forget to replace JSON by data in your stuff, and the $.getJSON call that I cannot use in a JSFiddle !
And remove window.Categories, just place Categories in a global scope.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NA5tt/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="categories">
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a class=""  onclick="Categories('Rock')"><span>Rock</span></a></li>
        <li><a class=""  onclick="Categories('Electro')"><span>Electro</span></a></li>
        <li><a class=""  onclick="Categories('Hip Hop')"><span>Hip Hop</span></a></li>
        <li><a class=""  onclick="Categories('Ambient')"><span>Ambient</span></a></li>
        <li><a class=""  onclick="Categories('Electronica')"><span>Electronica</span></a></li>
        <li><a class=""  onclick="Categories('Future Garage')"><span>Future Garage</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<hr />
<hr />
<div class="products"></div>
```

I'm using a static JSON var of course...

JS:

```
var JSON = {
    "Products": [
        {   "Name": "Pink Floyd",
         "Album": "The Best Of Pink Floyd: A Foot In The Door",
         "Label": "EMI UK",
         "Tracks":"Hey You, See Emily Play, The Happiest Days Of Our Lives, Another Brick in The Wall (Part 2), Have a cigar, Wish You Where Here, Time, The Great Gig in the Sky, Money, Comfortably Numb, High Hopes, Learning to Fly, The Fletcher Memorial Home, Shine On You Crazy Diamond, Brain Damage, Eclipse" ,
         "Price": "16.40",
         "Genre": "Rock"   ,
         "Source": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/38/AFootInTheDoorPinkFloyd.jpg/220px-AFootInTheDoorPinkFloyd.jpg",
         "Quantity": 10

        },
        {
            "Name": "Depeche Mode",
            "Album": "A Question Of Time",
            "Label": "Mute",
            "Tracks":"A Question Of Time, Black Celebration, Something To Do, Stripped, More Than A Party, A Question Of Time(extended), Black Celebration" ,
            "Price": "4.68" ,
            "Genre": "Rock",
            "Source": "http://dmremix.be/images/AQuestionOfTime.jpg",
            "Quantity": 10
        }
    ]
}

// window is JUST for the JSFiddle cause I'm in a jQuery scope.
window.Categories = function (Genre) {
    $(".products").empty();
    // Loop on JSON.Products
    $(JSON.Products).each(function(index, item) {
        // Compare to item instead of this
        if(Genre == item.Genre) {
            $('<div/>', {'class':'productname'}).text(item.Name).append(
                $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Album: '+item.Album}),
                $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails'}).append($('<img>').attr({src:item.Source,title:item.Name,alt:item.Name,class:'productimage'})),
                $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Genre: '+item.Genre}),
                $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Price: '+item.Price}),
                $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Quantity: '+item.Quantity}),
                $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Tracks: '+item.Tracks}),
                $('<div/>').append(
                    $('<button />', {'class':'productbutton'})
                    .text('Add To Cart.')
                    .click(function(){
                        $.fn.SaveToCart(i,item.Name, item.Album, item.Price);
                    })
                )
            ).appendTo(".products"); // .products instead of #products cause you're using a class
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Tried your code but it's not working. (This is what I did: http://pastebin.com/GjftP24h)

Comment: Yeah, you have to replace .products by #products if you change class='products' to id='products' !

Keep in mind that # refers to an id, and . to a class when selecting with jQuery !

Comment: For some reason it's still not working. Nothing is happening when I click.

Comment: And Replace, inside your Categories function, JSON.Products by another $.getJSON call on products.php, as you did it at the beginning :)

Comment: How come your JS Fiddle is working, and when I copy and paste, nothing happens?

Comment: I guess you are confusing .products and #products again, you gave me each one on your pastebin, what would you really do ?
I'm updating it in a way that should "work" for you, according your HTML structure !

Try this one in your environment !
http://pastebin.com/teCa3KBJ

Comment: Flo-Schield-Bobby .. Thanks! It's working now. I don't understand what you changed though. I had fixed the id/class thing but it was still not working.

Comment: Look at the Categories function, it's the main change !
I'm doing a $get.JSON again, but I keep thinking it's a bad idea.

You should store the data in a var from your server.
This one is a bit cleaner...

http://pastebin.com/BBTMHn22

Answer (score 2):

Fixed a few errors in your javascript code:

1) You are looping through each product, hence the `$(data.Products).each(function..`

2) `if(Genre == item.Genre){` to check for the genre properly

Try it out:

```
<script>

        function Categories(Genre)
        {
            $.getJSON('products.json', function(data) {
                $(".products").empty();
                $(data.Products).each(function(index, item){
                if(Genre == item.Genre){

                    $('<div/>', {'class':'productname',text:item.Name}).append(
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Album: '+item.Album}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails'}).append($('<img>').attr({src:item.Source,title:item.Name,alt:item.Name,class:'productimage'})),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Genre: '+item.Genre}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Price: '+item.Price}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Quantity: '+item.Quantity}),
                            $('<div/>', {'class':'productdetails', text:'Tracks: '+item.Tracks}),
                            $('<div/>').append(
                                    $('<button />', {'class':'productbutton'})
                                            .text('Add To Cart.')
                                            .click(function(){
                                                $.fn.SaveToCart(i,item.Name, item.Album, item.Price);
                                            })
                            )
                    ).appendTo("#products");
                }
            });


        });

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Nope, nothing happens. When an item is clicked, the page remains as it was.

Comment: I also noticed that you are emptying a div with class 'products' and then appending to a div with ID 'products'. Which is which?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can sort data objects, just sort the object and re create the table:

```
var obj={
    "Products": [
        {   "Name": "Pink Floyd",
            "Album": "The Best Of Pink Floyd: A Foot In The Door",
            "Label": "EMI UK",
            "Tracks":"Hey You, See Emily Play, The Happiest Days Of Our Lives, Another Brick in The Wall (Part 2), Have a cigar, Wish You Where Here, Time, The Great Gig in the Sky, Money, Comfortably Numb, High Hopes, Learning to Fly, The Fletcher Memorial Home, Shine On You Crazy Diamond, Brain Damage, Eclipse" ,
            "Price": "16.40",
            "Genre": "Rock"   ,
            "Source": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/38/AFootInTheDoorPinkFloyd.jpg/220px-AFootInTheDoorPinkFloyd.jpg",
            "Quantity": 10

        },
        {
            "Name": "Depeche Mode",
            "Album": "A Question Of Time",
            "Label": "Mute",
            "Tracks":"A Question Of Time, Black Celebration, Something To Do, Stripped, More Than A Party, A Question Of Time(extended), Black Celebration" ,
            "Price": "4.68" ,
            "Genre": "Rock",
            "Source": "http://dmremix.be/images/AQuestionOfTime.jpg",
            "Quantity": 10
        }
    ]
}

keys=["Genre","Name"];//Sorts by Genre then Name
obj.Products.sort(function(a,b){
  var ret=0,i=0;
  while(ret==0&&i<keys.length){
      ret=(a[keys[i]]>b[keys[i]])?1
        :(a[keys[i]]<b[keys[i]])?-1:0;
      i++;
   }
   return ret;
});
console.log(obj.Products)
```

Comment: of course no ! JSON is a data format, not a script file format !
Put that inside a <script> tag or in a .js file !